# Switching to child theme breaks menu names

Tags: menus, child-theme

When I switch to the child theme I am working on, the main menu uses the page names instead of the names that I gave it in the Appearance > Menu options. Happened to anyone else?

Comment: Is the menu still set correctly after the change?

Comment: Maybe you have to create a new menu and select it as your main navigation. It's hard to help you if you don't give us some more information.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. I am using the 500 Framework from Ignition Deck. Supposedly I am very easily meant to be able to create a child theme with only the style.css file and screenshot.png file but once I switch to the childtheme, the menus no longer work.

I have also tried your suggestion recreate the menu Kat but that didn't work.

Comment: Ben below said what I was going for! I am glad u figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom menus assigned to Menu Locations (in the Appearance, Menus, Manage Locations tab) are saved per theme.  So when you switched to your new theme, you lost that assignment.  Go to the Manage Locations tab and select your custom menus again.